# Schema Issue in XML file for Pyspark

Tags: xml, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark, schema

I am new in creating schema for xml. I used to work with xsd previously for parsing xml data.

I am trying to use the spark read format method. However I dont see the seller id in the schema. Is there a way I can get both seller_id and trade_id into my data.

```
df_trade_loan = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","trade").option("rootTag","loan").load("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/trades/*")
```

My xml file looks like as below.

```
<loan>
    <seller>
        <id>11</id>
    </seller>
    <trade id="67" type="Standard">
        <advance>
            <date>2011-03-09</date>
            <amount>16466.76</amount>
            <amount_gbp>16466.76</amount_gbp>
            <percentage>90.0</percentage>
        </advance>
        <discount>
            <percentage>1.0</percentage>
            <on>Facevalue</on>
        </discount>
        <expected_payment_date>2011-03-18 00:00:00 +0000</expected_payment_date>
        <settlement_date>2011-03-25</settlement_date>
        <arrears>
            <in_arrears>No</in_arrears>
            <in_arrears_on_date>nan</in_arrears_on_date>
        </arrears>
        <payment>
            <state>Paid</state>
        </payment>
        <price_grade>6</price_grade>
        <currency>GBP</currency>
        <face_value>
            <amount>18296.4</amount>
            <amount_gbp>18296.4</amount_gbp>
        </face_value>
        <outstanding_principal>
            <amount>0.0</amount>
            <amount_gbp>0.0</amount_gbp>
        </outstanding_principal>
        <crystalised_loss>
            <amount>nan</amount>
            <date>nan</date>
        </crystalised_loss>
        <gross_yield>
            <annualised>14.164038846995776</annualised>
        </gross_yield>
    </trade>
</loan>
```

The current schema looks like as below

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- advance: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount_gbp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- arrears: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- in_arrears: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- in_arrears_on_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- crystalised_loss: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- discount: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- on: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- expected_payment_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- face_value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount_gbp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- gross_yield: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- annualised: double (nullable = true)
 |-- outstanding_principal: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount_gbp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- payment: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price_grade: long (nullable = true)
 |-- settlement_date: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: since you specified the rowTag option as trade, it is generating the Row objects in dataframe for all the subfields in the trade. check if specifying the loan as rowTag will create the columns as seller_id an trade , then you can access all the sub fields for trade using the object notation in spark. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked really :). Can you vote for my question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_tade_seller = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","loan").option("rootTag","seller").load("adl://haaldatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/use_cases/recommendation/tempsubas/tempsubas/trades/*")
```

This code worked.